# Why all blocks at Blockchain are relayed by Unknown now?

Tags: blockchain, blockchain.info

only last week I could study which mining pool signed latest blocks.
Today this option turned status to Unknown

https://blockchain.info/

Any idea?

*(formatted table)*

```
Height  Age     Transactions    Total Sent  Relayed By  Size (kB)   Weight (kWU)
491728  31 minutes  352     196.23 BTC  Unknown     1,002.67    3,992.19
491727  31 minutes  266     920.01 BTC  Unknown     134.31  515.14
491726  33 minutes  1447    2,900.32 BTC    Unknown     1,017.02    3,996.92
491725  39 minutes  290     822.51 BTC  Unknown     132.29  494.91
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Issue seems to be fixed.
Blockchain back in order, blocks relayed by real names of mining pools.
Thank you Blockchain

```
Height  Age     Transactions    Total Sent  Relayed By  Size (kB)   Weight (kWU)
```

492019  1 hour 4 minutes    2628    18,615.76 BTC   ViaBTC  1,035.85    3,992.75
492018  1 hour 7 minutes    2662    19,214.10 BTC   BitFury     1,036.1     3,992.5
492017  1 hour 11 minutes   2856    4,369.50 BTC    ViaBTC  1,038.23    3,992.72
492016  1 hour 13 minutes   2815    6,719.06 BTC    AntPool     999.17  3,728.27

Answer (score 1):

There was an update to the site that changed its behavior to no longer properly identify who relayed blocks.

Until they fix the issue, you can use other blockexplorers to find the information.

Given your stated usecase, I suggest you look at http://coin.dance/blocks

Comment: thank you, since my conference paper abstract has been accepted I need to attach 50+ pages of stats + charts. Since coin.dance publishes blocks by mining pool chart, tell me how to access raw data as provided by the Blockchain in the past and how to download block headers ?  api.blockcypher.com/v1/btc/main/blocks/491658 is great but made alike modification, setting every nonce to "0", making block data useless for any R&D study.  any idea ?

Comment: from https://blockchain.info/pools      " A large portion of Unknown blocks does not mean an attack on the network, it simply means we have been unable to determine the origin."

Comment: I dont know if coin.dance/blocks can give you raw data. there is many block explorers available (google for bitcoin block explorer), and you can always download and setup a bitcoin node then use the jsonrpc functions to query the data directly from you own node.

Comment: Thank you Jonathan,  knowing the right search term "bitcoin block explorer" is a key to success. Still work hard to get access to download all block headers in json or another format.